# How to Register C#.net DLL on Ubuntu? I am not able to Use Regasm.exe on Ubuntu10.10

Tags: c#, ubuntu, dll, regasm

I have used GACutil command to copy a .NEt DLL into GAC,  and i am trying to Register the DLL using "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727>regasm testdll.dll /tlb:testdll.tlb"  using this command

I am executing this on Wine Command Prompt in Ubuntu 10.10

but it says "fixme:regasm:wmain stub: L"regasm" "testdll.dll" L "/tlb:testdll.tlb"

Please Help Me how to register the C#.net DLL on Ubuntu 10.10

Answer (score 1):

just googling your title..

[How to register a DLL?](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=885264)

you need Wine program

```
wine cmd
regsvr32 C:\windows\system32\<COM_DLL>.dll
```

if you know spanish, also check [here](http://doc.ubuntu-es.org/Wine)

Comment: Thanks i had tried this , since it is a C#.net dll it says  DLLRegisterServer Not implemented in "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\EvoluteIMP.dll", I need to know how to use Regasm command on Ubuntu 10.10 (Similar to the way how we use on VisualStudio command Prompt in Windows)  . Pls Help